# reuse the value of str_split()

Tags: php

I have a long string of number , I want to divide them into chunks of length 8 then get their characters out of this ascii number.

when I use `bindec()` after `str_split($string,8)` it gives me wrong value. 
I can not figure out where is the problem as `str_split()` divides the string correctly.

```
$key = '101101011';
numbersToletters($key);

function numbersToletters($string) {
    $pool = str_split($string, 8);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($pool); $i++) {
        $bin = $pool[$i];
        $n = bindec($bin);
        echo chr($n) . "<br>";
    }
}
```

the output I receive out of bindec('101101011') is 81 while it is 363 and should return k

this works fin for example

```
$number = bindec($key);
echo $number;
echo "<br>".chr($number) ."<br>";
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: And what is the wrong value you obtained?

Comment: Maybe it's only a missing utf8_encode() on the chr($n)? (just a guess without knowing the expected values)

Comment: `chr` function only returns one character ([see chr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)). Maybe it the problem?

Comment: http://ideone.com/us8AqC

Comment: Regarding your edit. `101101011` are 9 characters, but you are splitting the string after 8

Comment: the expected output the the right value a decimal number from the return binary. @RajdeepPaul

Comment: @Rangad
I am trying to explain it but it is a big string of numbers 
$key = "0011010000101101101101011010100000011101110110111001000000000100";

Comment: @segarci i know that I need only one character out of this number

Comment: `bindec('101101011');` is 363. but in your code you have 9 chars in `$key` so take first 8 `bindec('10110101');` that is 181. where did you get the `81`? https://eval.in/497645

Comment: @eval
that is right , you solved my problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your code and nothing is wrong. Var_dump show true values and I translated with my head to be sure.

```
array (size=8)
0 => string '00110100' (length=8)
1 => string '00101101' (length=8)
2 => string '10110101' (length=8)
3 => string '10101000' (length=8)
4 => string '00011101' (length=8)
5 => string '11011011' (length=8)
6 => string '10010000' (length=8)
7 => string '00000100' (length=8)

52
45
181
168
29
219
144
4
```

> Check on http://www.asciitable.com/

```
    $key = '0011010000101101101101011010100000011101110110111001000000000100';
    $pool = str_split($key,8);

    var_dump($pool);

    for($i = 0 ;$i < count($pool) ; $i++)
    {
        $n= bindec($pool[$i]);
        var_dump($n);
        echo chr($n) . "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the call to `chr` function:

```
$key = '0011010000101101101101011010100000011101110110111001000000000100';
numbersToletters($key);

function numbersToletters($string) {
    $pool = str_split($string, 8);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($pool); $i++) {
        $bin = $pool[$i];
        $n = bindec($bin);
        echo $n . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the problem char do no problem 
this return as following 
52 which is right 
45 whiich is right 
81 which is wrong it suppose to be binary 101101011 which is 363
so as the following numbers
101010001 gives => 68 wrong 
00011101 gives => 29 right
110110112 gives => 19 wrong

Comment: Why are you suddenly using binary numbers with 9 positions (363) out of nowhere?